# Training a machine learning model on data that has several rows for each user

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, dataset, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset consisting of log files from a smartphone application. Currently, it creates a row each time a user clicks on something, i.e. a user clicks on the homepage, and a new row is created containing the longitude and latitude of the device as well as for how long the page has been open.

The rows also contain some user-specific data in regards to age and gender, due to the nature of the app, some of the columns in these rows are left as NAN because they arent populated unless a user clicks on X page in the app. That means that the Battery Percentage column is blank unless the user clicks on the Battery page in the app. In this new row, it will have the Battery page as the source and the Battery Percentage column will no longer be a NAN value.

The way users are tracked is with a session-id that acts as the index. This way a session-id can have several rows that represent each action the user has taken in the app.

My question is in regards to how to properly format the dataset to prepare it for machine learning. I am unbeknownst as how to properly use this data in its current format for machine learning tasks since a session can span over several rows where there would be a lot of NAN values as a result of the way the logging is done. I am wondering if there is a way to handle the dataset in an efficient matter or perform some formatting techniques that would make it into a 1 row=1 user dataset.

The response variable will take its form in the amount of time spent in a zone that is within the lattitude and longitude of X and Y in the real world. For example, I want to predict the time a user will spend in zone 1, based on their actions in the app and movements using the logged latitude and longitudes. The zone can be anything from a bench to a shop, time spent in the zone is denominated in seconds. In the dataset, the response variable is represented in a row with all the other columns/features where the type of action is "Entered zone" from which the response variable column will begin counting until the user leaves the zone area triggering the "Exited zone" type of action.

[image]

Comment: You've asked us how to format the data set, but you haven't explained anything about what you want to learn from the data. This is crucial!

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen my  accounts are already linked. It also says so on the merge formula.